# What does the "s" do in this code?

Tags: ruby, syntax

The following code is a Ruby implementation of a Caesar cypher:

```
def caeser(s,n)s.gsub(/./){|c|(c.ord+n).chr}end
```

It was given as a solution to a problem here: http://www.sitepoint.com/ruby-golf/

What is the purpose of the "s" at the end of `caeser(s,n)s`.

Without the "s", the code doesn't work.

Comment: Umm, what does this have to do with Ruby on Rails 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it look like this:

```
    def caeser(s,n)
     s.gsub(/./){|c|(c.ord+n).chr}
    end
```

Comment: thank you so much!!! Wow, that totally went over my head. Mind==blown.

Thank you so much for you help!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
def caeser(s,n)s.gsub(/./){|c|(c.ord+n).chr}end
```

In the code above

```
def caesar(s,n)
```

is the method declaration block

```
s.gsub(/./){|c|c.ord+n).chr}
```

This is the method block, where the function's code is actually executed

```
end
```

This statement terminates the method

The above function is poorly formatted, and proper convention would be this

```
def caesar(s,n)
  s.gsub(/./){|c|(c.ord+n).chr}
end
```

It's better to put your declaration statement, method block and closing statement all on separate lines as this lessens confusion.